# What is the fastest, easiest way to get several records into a database using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new with Ruby on Rails and want to get several records into the SQLite3 database so that I can manipulate the data. I am following a lesson, and wonder what is the fastest, most effective way to get the data into the database, which has four tables (includes one join table)?

Are there any plugins which are good for this?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Faker](http://rubyforge.org/projects/faker) library and Rail's new [seed functionality](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding).

Answer (score 0):

Have you got data already? Is it already in a database? If so the easiest way is to just configure rails to connect to the database.

Other than that you'll want to look into seeding. [This railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) explains the process.